# Find index of less or equal value in list recursively (python)

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search

Got task to find indexes of value and double that value in input list.
In input first line we get list range, second - list of values, third - value to find.
The output is 2 numbers - indexes of equal or higher value and double the value. If there is none, return -1

Example input:

```
6
1 2 4 4 6 8
3
```

Example output:

```
3 5
```

What i got so far is standart binary search func, but i dont get how to make it search not only for exact number but nearest higher.

```
def binarySearch(arr, x, left, right):
    if right <= left:
        return -1
    mid = (left + right) // 2
    if arr[mid] >= x: 
        return mid
    elif x < arr[mid]:          
        return binarySearch(arr, x, left, mid)
    else: 
        return binarySearch(arr, x, mid + 1, right)

def main():
    n = int(input())
    k = input().split()
    q = []
    for i in k:
        q.append(int(i))
    s = int(input())
    res1 = binarySearch(q, s, q[0], (n-1))
    res2 = binarySearch(q, (s*2), q[0], (n-1))
    print(res1, res2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The input is:

```
6
1 2 4 4 6 8
3
```

And output:

```
3 4
```

Comment: Your output doesn't match the problem. If you're looking for 3 then the nearest (higher) value is 4 which is at index 2. Double 3 is 6 which exists at index 4. So your output should be 2, 4. Also, is the list of numbers guaranteed to be in ascending order? Why do you need to use recursion?

Comment: @Vlad yes, list of numbers in ascending order, i am looking for nearest (higher) value, sorry if i explained it bad thou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modified binary search which will return the base zero index of a value if found or the index of the next highest value in the list.

```
def bsearch(lst, x):
    L = 0
    R = len(lst) - 1
    while L <= R:
        m = (L + R) // 2
        if (v := lst[m]) == x:
            return m
        if v < x:
            L = m + 1
        else:
            R = m - 1
    return L if L < len(lst) else -1


data = list(map(int, '1 2 4 4 6 8'.split()))

for x in range(10):
    print(x, bsearch(data, x))
```

**Output:**

```
0 0
1 0
2 1
3 2
4 2
5 4
6 4
7 5
8 5
9 -1
```

Comment: thanks, it seem to work, but is there any option to do that recursively? thats the point of task

Comment: @r3tr0 I didn't realise this was homework. You should be asking your tutor why you need recursion for this and also ask what could happen with a very long list. The title of this website should give you a clue

Comment: thats the task based on recursion, blows my mind so far, thanks anyways